# How to deal with CORS in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, amazon-product-api

I have wrote the react app from which i am calling the amazon-product API using the the module `amazon-product-api` but it gives me CORS issue.

I am getting Following error

> Failed to load https://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=aasc&AssociateTag=asd&Condition=All&Domain=webservices.amazon.in&IdType=ASIN&IncludeReviewsSummary=True No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

For temporary solution i have added cors extension to get the things work.

Comment: Did you try `mode: cors` in fetch request ?

Comment: @Alex ya i know its been asked many times, but here i am using amazon-product-api module to fetch the data from amazon, i am not getting how to add CORS header in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`amazon-product-api` is a Node.js client for the Amazon Product Advertising API and **should be used on the server-side**.

If you're using it on the client-side with React, that's the reason you get the CORS issue.